# Kerberos Support for FileNet .Net client hosted on IIS

Tags: .net, iis, single-sign-on, kerberos, filenet-p8

We have .NET applications which are integrated with FileNet and connect to custom FileNet application hosted on IIS which retrieves documents.

We ahve requirement to pass pass user credentials from .Net apps connection to FileNet. However, we dont want to pass password to FileNet web service.

So we enabled kerberos application in application server in Filenet and we can authenticate user using Kerberos credentials which gets logged in user.

However, we need to  access to FileNet from mobile applications which are outside domain and access FileNet app in IIS.

Is there any way we can impersonate user from logged in .NET app and request Kerberos token for that user programatically and pass the Kerberos token to FileNet web service? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A few years ago, Microsoft had ISA Server which can translate forms authentication to Kerberos, https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sooraj-sec/2009/12/05/owa-publishing-using-kerberos-constrained-delegation-method-for-authentication-delegation/ They discontinued the product, and you should now search for a third party solution, or develop your own.